# What do I need to know before I can read Categories by Aristotle?

Tags: aristotle

I'm a complete beginner, no philosophical knowledge whatsoever. What do I need to know before I can read Categories? I don't understand what is going on whenever the phrases 'is said of this' or ' is said in this' come up or whenever various other jargon crops up. I feel that at my level, even reading commentaries on categories is outside my grasp.

Comment: Some introductory book on [Aristotle](https://books.google.it/books?id=I3HMSHAHHDcC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: The relevant parts of books on the [history of logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FtXAwgy1w9cC&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

(1)Reading the *Categories* without some knowledge of Greek is a total waste of time. As a minimum you should be able to compare how the key words of Aristotle have been replaced by rather arbitrary translations. (E.g. 'ousia' is essence but the accepted word is substance; 'atom' is atom but the accepted word is individual, etc) Many such peculiarities are due to the fact the theology hijacked much of the original philosophical vocabulary.

(2)Also you should bear in mind that the Categories seriously diverges from what Aristotle appears to mean elsewhere, mostly in *Metaphysics*. (He says, for instance, that species and genera do not really exist, only atoms) His stance in Categories is obviously nominalistic but mentioning that usually draws howls of indignation: commentators do prodigious contortions in order to avoid saying it.

(3)It should not escape your notice that when Aristotle wrote the treatise grammar did not exist in an clear cut form. The best way to read *the Categories* is as Emile Benveniste proposed: as discovery of grammatical forms.

---

Benveniste  "Categories of Thought and Language" is translated in *Problems of general linguistics"* U of Miami Press 1971 p.55. An extended treatment of this idea is Michael R. Baumer, "Chasing Aristotle’s Categories Down the Tree of Grammar", J. of Phphical Research, Vol.18, 1993,p.341-449

Answer (score 1):

First, I have not read the Categories myself and was only recently planning to dip in. But for this or any other reading I would strongly urge some historical context to help imagine a world prior to the work and the situation to which that work responds.

Kneale and Kneale's venerable "The Development of Logic" might be a useful source. As an aside, they note that the Organon was collected by Aristotle's later transcribers and some have questioned the inclusion of the Categories, which is more metaphysics than logic and, at the same time, inconsistent with other aspects of Aristotle's metaphysics.

They also describe the Categories as one of Aristotle's persistent attempts to dispel Plato's theory of Forms. So here again, historical context is helpful. Sorry to say, but if you haven't done any philosophy at all, I'm not sure the Categories is the place to start, unless you are doing it in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps read first an introduction to classical philosophy? There are many, very good ones; I can recommend [Peter Adamson's](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/classical-philosophy-9780199674534?lang=en&cc=gb#).

Comment: Bit of a strange recommendation. Let's see your advice concerning learning Greek would mean that we would all have to spend our lifetimes learning: German, Latin, French, Chinese, Arabic, etc. before we could benefit from reading translations, is that what you really mean?

Comment: I'm not seeing the analogy at all :) I think it's very sensible to read a modern introduction to Greek philosophy before moving on to the primary sources.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to the person who said that you need to read Aristotle in Greek!

Comment: Oh! That analogy I get :)

Answer (score 0):

In Greek or English, the Categories is not an easy work to read or make sense of if you come at it as a complete beginner in philosophy. You need a translation (unless you know Classical Greek) and a commentary which will convey an accurate sense of the Greek terms and make clear the philosophical issues at play. The best candidate I know of is J.L. Ackrill, Aristotle: Categories and De Interpretatione, Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1993. Ackrill was both a Greek scholar and very competent philosopher.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at :

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/

- No prior knowledge, only careful reading and note-taking.

---

-A subject is " what stands below" , what " supports" ( " sub-jectum", " upo - keimenon").

- A subject can support a predicate ( *subjectum praedicationis* = subject of predication). Here subject is taken in the logico-grammatical sense.

In that case, what the subject supports is " *said of*" the subject, that is , is predicated *of it*, attributed to it ( in a proposition, or predicative sentence, that says something *of* something).

- A subject can support a "quality" in the broad sense  ( *subjectum inhaesionis*= *subject of inherence* ).

In that case, what the subject supports is "*in*" the subject, " *attached to*" the subject  in the sense that it *depends on* the subject for its existence. What is " in" a subject is called an " accident" ( litterally: what falls on a subject).

- Examples :

Aristotle  is the attribution subject ( *subjectum praedicationis*) of " learned", for " Aristotle is learned " is a true sentence.

But the predicate "learned" is not " in" Aristotle .

The corresponding entity that is " in "Aristotle is " knowledge" or " science". 
So Aristotle is the *subjectum inhaesionis* of science.

And one can see  that, symmetrically, " knowlzedge " is not said of Aristotle.

One does not say : " Aristotle is knowledge" , but "Aristotle is learned".

- ***These concepts of " said of " a subject and " in" a subject are required , for Aristotle , to define the concept of a substance ( first substance) *** : that which is neither said of a subject nor in a subject ( that is , neither a universal attributed to a subject, nor an accident , depending on something else for its existence).